# 1-loop diagrams in Scalar Yang-Mills

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, yang-mills

**Disclaimer:** I've been calculating the renormalization constants $Z_i$ for the ScalarQED seen as the abelian limit of the Scalar Yang-Mills, and I know that I've made some mistakes because I find the correct $Z_3$ for the vector propagator, but I don't find $Z_1=Z_2$ for the scalar propagator and vertex (and I know that this should hold in an abelian theory), and I'm trying to figure out what I missed.

- Are the following diagrams the only (divergent) diagrams in $d=4$ to 1-loop order in Scalar Yang-Mills with minimal coupling for the scalar propagator and the vertex?

[image]

- I considered the self-loop (in green) to be zero as the fields in the theory are massless. Is this a mistake?
- I couldn't find any combinatory factors to be different from 1 for any of the diagrams that I drew, as the scalars are complex and therefore have a charge. Is this wrong?
- I think the only diagrams that shouldn't be considered in the abelian limit are the orange ones.    Is there a reason why maybe other diagrams aren't to be considered either?

Comment: So what do you find instead for $Z_1$ and $Z_2$? You might want to compare with e.g. Srednicki chapter 65.